# Connecting Frontend API application to Backend database

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

Can someone please help me complete this scenario as I have everything running successfully but with no end result as expected. I have a PostgreSQL database and Redis (back-end) Pods along with a front-end API application that I will be using to send API requests. Unfortunately, after setting up everything and making sure they are all running on the Kubernetes dashboard, when sending an API request there is nothing happening as if there is no connection between my services. Before desperately posting here I did some research to find a solution to this problem, I tried this tutorial of using a [ingress-service](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/10/25/deploying-a-full-stack-application-to-google-kubernetes-engine/) to connect my services but did not work. I also came across this [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/) that will connect my back-end service to my front-end service using some sort of upstream configuration file but it did not do the trick.

Here is my YAML configuration files if anyone is interested:

> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>    name: dictionary-project
>    labels:
>      app: net
> spec:
>   replicas: 1
>   selector:
>     matchLabels:
>       app: dictionary
>       tier: frontend
>   template:
>     metadata:
>       labels:
>         app: dictionary
>         tier: frontend
>     spec:
>        hostNetwork: true
>        containers:
>        - name: dictionaryapi
>          image: amin/dictionary_server_api:latest
>          ports:
>          - containerPort: 400
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>    name: dictionary-service
>    labels:
>      app: net
> spec:
>   selector:
>       app: dictionary
>       tier: frontend
>   type: NodePort 
>   ports:
>   - nodePort: 31003
>     port: 67
>     targetPort: 400
>     protocol: TCP
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>     name: postgrebackendservice
>     labels:
>        run: backend
> spec:
>  selector:
>       app: postgres
>       tier: backend
>  type: ClusterIP
>  ports:
>     - port: 5432
>       targetPort: 5432
>       name: postgresdb
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>     name: reddisbackendservice
>     labels:
>         run: backend
> spec:
>   selector:
>       app: reddis
>       tier: backend
>   type: ClusterIP
>   ports:
>   - port: 6379
>     targetPort: 6379
>     name: client
>   - port: 16379
>     targetPort: 16379
>     name: gossip
> ```

Output of all services:

```
Name:                     dictionary-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=net
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=dictionary,tier=frontend
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.126.146.18
Port:                     <unset>  67/TCP
TargetPort:               400/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31003/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.x.x:400
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

Name:              postgrebackendservice
Namespace:         default
Labels:            run=backend
Annotations:       Selector:  app=postgres,tier=backend
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.182.374.13
Port:              postgresdb  5432/TCP
TargetPort:        5432/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.x.x:5432
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

Name:              reddisbackendservice
Namespace:         default
Labels:            run=backend
Annotations:       Selector:  app=reddis,tier=backend
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.182.0.60
Port:              client  6379/TCP
TargetPort:        6379/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.x.x:6379
Port:              gossip  16379/TCP
TargetPort:        16379/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.x.x:16379
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

I am testing my front-end API application on a web browser by sending a http://{workernodeIP}:31003/swagger but the page is not loading due to no connection to the server.

#### Cluster information:

```
Kubernetes version: v1.18.6
Environment being used: bare-metal, 1 VM Master Node and 1 VM Worker Node
Installation method: kubeadm
Host OS: Ubuntu 18.04
CNI and version: calico
CRI and version: Docker 19.03.6
```

Comment: Edit the question to add output of `kubectl describe svc reddisbackendservice, postgrebackendservice,dictionary-service`

Comment: Dear Arghya, Updated my question with the requested service output, please note that all endpoints are of the same workernode IP address.

Comment: Double check if dictionary app is listening on port 400?

Comment: Dear @ArghyaSadhu, you were right my dictionary app was running on port 80 when i checked using sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN. But i specifically assigned the containerPort to be 400 why did it run on port 80. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#container-v1-core)

> **containerPort**:
> List of ports to expose from the container. **Exposing a port here gives
> the system additional information about the network connections a
> container uses, but is primarily informational**. Not specifying a port
> here DOES NOT prevent that port from being exposed. Any port which is
> listening on the default "0.0.0.0" address inside a container will be
> accessible from the network. Cannot be updated.

As you can see `containerPort` is information and does not make the app listen on that port. For really making the app listen on port `400` you need change port in code.

Comment: Question please, as mentioned above I am using a service type NodePort for my dictionary application, so basically the port 31003 should work right?

Comment: Yes it should work. First check if you are able to access it directly via POD IP using curl from another pod or using `kubectl port-forward`